# Connecting to Azure SQL Server Fails

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I created a Azure SQL Database Server as shown in the image below

[image]

with only microsoft-entra authentication enabled, later when i try to connect to it through SSMS, it gives me the error on selecting windows authentication:

*Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40607)*

Is this an issue with my local ms sql server, I had installed sql server 2022 recently and was able to connect to the localhost.

Other Questions alongside this

1] I had seen *SELECT @@VERSION* command returning ms sql server 2012, when I ran on azure sql database server connected through SSMS. Can we update it or can we select version when creating the database?

2] On running sqlcmd -L command in my local cmd returns "?" for all the attributes while several other stackoverflow questions had some values returned, will this cause any problems?

I am new to azure and sql, can anyone please help me with this, I am unable to get my head around this.

Comment: Azure SQL Database supports AAD auth, not Windows auth. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview?view=azuresql

Comment: What do you mean by my "a sql in Azure"? There are multiple different Database solutions available in Azure, such as Azure Managed Instance, Azure SQL DAtabase, Azure Synapse, PostgreSQL, MySQL, CosmosDB, to name a few.

Comment: @ThomA i meant a sql database and its server. I have corrected the question.

Comment: That actually doesn't add any clarity.

Comment: I have added a picture of what I was talking about @ThomA , but anyways, the first comment clear that out. But I am still left with my other 2 questions.

Comment: Please only ask one question per *question*

Comment: SQL is a language, standardized by ISO. Microsoft has tried to hijack that term naming their product SQL Server etc. But there are dozens and dozens of SQL databases, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can't use Windows Authentication to connect to an Azure SQL Server, you need to use Azure AD (Entra ID) Authentication:

[image: Auth options in SSMS 19.1]

You would use 'Universal with MFA' and enter the e-mail address of the admin user you defined when you built the server, which will then open a browser window to perform the login.

Comment: i was able to connect, thank you very much. If possible can you please elaborate on my other 2 questions below the pic.

Comment: Re: the version, I think you're referring to something like this?

`Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Sep 29 2023 18:13:26   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation `

This isn't SQL Server 2012, this is the Azure SQL version which is a different versioning number to the onprem SQL Server versioning numbers (also worth mentioning that a version starting with 12 on-prem would be SQL Server 2014).

Comment: `sqlcmd -L` on it's own won't return any servers, because there isn't an instance running locally for you. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921002/18408939